# How do I save Clementine in the Drug Store myself?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I am in the drug store and Clementine is attacked by a Walker. I stumble down, and try to reach her, yet I am not fast enough and she is saved by someone else instead. Afterwards, there is a notice that Clementine will remember I did not save her. This makes me think it is possible to save her myself.

Is it possible to save her by myself? If so, how am I supposed to save Clementine myself?

Comment: I have to add yet again that this is an issue with my graphic card. Anyone using a Nvidia of the 7xxx line, in my case 7300GT, will most likely stumble upon this weird behavior, as the driver does not render transparency correctly. Selecting Clementine becomes a matter of sheer luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can save her by yourself. You can't not fall down on the ground, but after you fall, if you can quickly select her while you're in a daze you can save her yourself so that she remembers it. You can watch the video walk through below (starts at about 5:36 in).